# How to merge two UV sets in Maya

Tags: maya

I'm struggling to make [this](https://anonfiles.com/file/fac251655b171bb347424453b9b3f9e3) scene to show the textures in the viewport, it was imported from [this](https://anonfiles.com/file/952173db457042822c80af53b22738ca) COLLADA file, and it renders ok in mental ray.

Activating textures (key 6) in the view port won't work, I think it is because it has three UV sets, the first one (map1) show the PNG texture but has no UV geometry, while the remaining two have some geometry in them but have no texture image.

This is how it looks rendered with mental ray, and textures activated in the viewport.

[image]

These are the three UV sets, what I want is to **merge map2 and map3 into map1**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you press `6`?

Comment: @mhlester Yep, it didn't work

Comment: What file format are the textures? What does it look like instead? Black? Gray? Wireframe? Green?

Comment: @mhlester The textures used in the DAE file are PNG with 32 bits per pixel (R8G8B8A8), I'm not sure whether those are converted to other format by maya

Comment: @mhlester also in the UV Texture Editor I have three UV Sets, map1, map2, and map3, but only map2 and map3 have polygons mapped in them, but those don't have an image linked, just map1 shows the image

Comment: "In the shader attributes, under hardware texture you can set which channel is displayed (color, bump etc.)" - http://simplymaya.com/forum/showthread.php?t=11902

Comment: @ntgCleaner I think merging all the UV sets into one map would do the job but I don't know how to do it, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: That might be a huge PITA, You will have to redo all of the textures or at least resize them, assuming the UV maps are in the same relative space within themselves.

Comment: Here's a quick tutorial for UV mapping in case you want to do it.http://www.jawa9000.com/Technical/UVs/UVs.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the uvs you want to merge over and go to

Create UVs - Copy UVs to UV set - Select the uv set you want to merge with.

If the uv set you're merging to already has UVs for the faces you selected, it will overwrite them.